# MVC4 Show model state Error Message on Homepage Login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a login form on my homepage.  It works - but I want to display an error message if the pw is wrong.  My code is below.  How do I return to the same page but retrieve the modelstate error in the Index method?

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult HomeLogin(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit

Since you are using the RedirectToAction method the option that comes to my mind would be to use the TempData object.

In the controller method:

```
TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "The user name or password provided is incorrect.";
```

In your view you can check if the message is set and display it if it is.

```
@if(TempData["ErrorMessage"] != null)
{
    <p class="errorMessage">@TempData["ErrorMessage"]</p>
}
```

Comment: The thing is I don't think the Index method knows that there is an error bc I am using return RedirectToAction("Index").